# iOS 16.4, SwiftUI, TextField always on top of keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, ios16

I've been playing around with SwiftUI List view where each "cell" contains a multiline TextView.

When user selects a TextView at the bottom of the view, the chosen "cell" with TextView scrolls upward to stay visible above keyboard (as expected).

However, I've encountered an issue: when a user enters more text that extends beyond a single line, the TextField doesn't scroll up. Consequently, the text remains hidden from view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PlaygroundView: View {
    
    let sections = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4", "Section 5", "Section 6"]
    @State private var sectionText = Array(repeating: "", count: 6)
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sections.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Section(header: Text(sections[index])) {
                    TextField("Enter text", text: $sectionText[index], axis: .vertical)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an out of the box solution available to ensure that a TextField remains consistently visible on top of the keyboard?

Video: https://imgur.com/a/RgMQksp